# Testing date parser with timezone in Java

Tags: java, junit, date-parsing

What seems like a simple enough problem is giving me a major headache with date parsing.

In my java project, I have a custom date parser util class which handles all the different varieties of date string formats it may encounter.

I recently had to add the following use case:

```
DateFormat fileDateImport = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz");<br />
return fileDateImport.parse(stringToParse);
```

I now want to test this functionality, but I've been having problems because the date isn't translating as I would expect. I've tried a few things, here's what my test looks like now (my computers local settings are in CST).

```
Date returnDate = DateParser.parseDate("Wed, 24 Sep 2014 00:00:00 BST");
final SimpleDateFormat convertedTime = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
convertedTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("BST"));
assertEquals("24092014000000", convertedTime.format(returnDate));
```

The returnDate object reads "Tue Sep 23 18:00:00 CDT 2014", which is what I would expect. CST is 6 hours behind BST. However, I don't want to check against the toString() of this date, since this test could be potentially run in different time zones.

The final output of the format is "24092014050000". I'm not sure how it's getting that time, it jumps ahead 11 hours from the original returnDate.

I've tried setting the returnDate time in a calendar object, but I get the same result.

Anyone a little more handy with dates than me have any ideas?

Comment: If you are able to use Java 8 a much better Date model was introduced, look for `ZonedDateTime`.  Meantime remember that BST = GMT + 1.

Comment: That's good to know, but unfortunately I have no control over that! Our current Java version is 7.

Comment: Not an immediate Solution but probably better to use HH rather than hh. you might find it is 5pm not am. And try outputting the zones (Z) too to help you work out what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you'll have to use "Europe/London" instead of "BST", if you mean British Standard Time (or "Asia/Dhaka" if you mean Bangladesh Standard Time).

```
 convertedTime.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
```

See http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4257424

Comment: Thanks Giovanni, that did the trick! And that explains the 11 hours time difference, it must have been using Bangladesh Standard Time.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, one solution is to call `setTimeZone()` in your `convertedTime` `DateFormat` and pass it the result of `getTimeZone()` from your `fileDateImport` `DateFormat`. That is, something like -

```
DateFormat fileDateImport =new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
try {
    Date d = fileDateImport.parse("Wed, 24 Sep 2014 00:00:00 BST");
    final SimpleDateFormat convertedTime =new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmss");
    convertedTime.setTimeZone(fileDateImport.getTimeZone());
    if ("24092014000000".equals(convertedTime.format(d))) {
        System.out.println("Passed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed");   
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which outputs `Passed` because it passes your unit test. The primary differences are using the TimeZone from the parser (and using `HH` instead of `hh` for hours).

Comment: -1 The OP shows that he is calling `setTimeZone` with the desired time zone `BST`. The timezone of the `fileDateInport` is `CST` as has been stated.

Comment: @JohnB Except, if you run the code above it passes the unit test that OP posted. Note that I use HH instead of hh in the format string. Also, *However, I don't want to check against the toString() of this date, since this test could be potentially run in different time zones.*

Comment: I think you might be right in that I think the issue might be `HH` vs `hh`. By using `hh` and not parsing `am/pm` there is no way to distinguish `am` vs `pm` so the result could easily be `12 hours` off. I would just suggest updating your answer to focus on that instead of setting the `timezone` with the OP is doing.

Comment: That sounds about right if it is parsed as 12 noon BST which would be 11am GMT internally.  then setting the timezone explicitly moves it to 10am GMT internally 11am BST.

Comment: @Caleryn Notice there's also a day-light savings time adjustment for the OP clock (CDT vs CST).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch agreed but I think it is the one between the internal representation in GMT and the resetting to BST that matters unless there is a System.out call in which the default `Locale` would again come into play.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I've changed my date formatters/parsers to use "HH" instead of "hh". However, I'm using Giovanni's solution as it is the easiest and exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate the help though!